# Update/Delete an Item in DyanamoDb using Glue Job

Tags: python, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I am working on accessing the DynamoDB from the Glue Job using pyspark. Currently I am writing an entry in the Dynamo DB using the write_dynamic_frame_from_options method, which is working fine.

Now I need to update or delete the existing item in the DynamoDB is there a way to do it.

I checked the documentation on AWS Glue Context, but the options are there only to write, not update or delete

Answer (score 1):

you can refer below page for more details :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#pyspark-drop_fields-example

you can try something like below code to delete existing items in dynodb, after deleting the object write the updated object to dynamo :

```
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame


df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={
        "dynamodb.input.tableName": "my-table",
        "dynamodb.input.key.partitionKey": "key1",
        "dynamodb.input.key.sortKey": "key2"
    }
)

df = df.drop_fields(dynamic_frame.schema().field_names())


glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    frame=df,
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={
        "dynamodb.output.tableName": "my-table",
        "dynamodb.output.operation": "delete"
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response @Anujsharma, but while reading the data from the dynamodb table i am not able to filter using the given "dynamodb.input.key.partitionKey" and "dynamodb.input.key.sortKey"

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB connector with Spark does not have the ability to delete or update, it can only use `PutItem` which adds new data or overwrites existing data.

Should you need to `Update` or `Delete` you will need to do so using a boto3 function and not Spark.